# Change default mentality in FIFA 15

Tags: pc, fifa-15

I started a career in FIFA 15 and I noticed that when I start a match, my team has "Defensive" (I don't know if this is the correct translation in English, I'm playing in other language) mentality set as default and every game I have to remember to change it.
Is there a way to set another mentality as default?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Game Settings

> Enter the option to edit your console (keyboard/joystick/ gamepad) > move at the bottom of your controller options and there you will see how to change the tactics in-game

Hope it helps